# Getting Invalid bareword error

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to give a '\n' at the end of every line provided if it gets **{** in the end.

so I wrote the command

```
set fp [open "test.tcl" r]
set new_file [open "final.tcl" w+]
while {![eof $fp]} {
     get $fp line
     if $line {$'{'} {
     puts $new_file '\n'
     } 
}
```

but its not working and sometimes it gives error "Invalid bareword".
Can you please help me out.

Comment: You probably mean gets instead of get, the if command is mangled, and you aren't printing the text line. Also, the file must be flushed or closed before changes appear.

Comment: Your code will (probably) be trying to evaluate each line as an expression. It's unlikely that this is something you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
set fp [open test.tcl]
set new_file [open final.tcl w+]
while {[gets $fp line] >= 0} {
    if {[regexp {\{$} $line]} {
        puts $new_file $line\n
    } else {
        puts $new_file $line
    }
}
close $fp
close $new_file
```

?

Documentation: [close](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/close.htm), [gets](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/gets.htm), [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm), [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [while](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm)

Comment: Works. Thanks and what if I want to put \t to all the more upcoming lines unless I get ' } '. Hope you don't mind helping me again.

Comment: @DhruvPaul: sorry, but no. Prettyprinting is harder than it looks, and can be quite frustrating. To begin with, regular expressions aren't going to be of much help in the long run: you need to go through the source code character by character and work out methods to distinguish between different kinds of brace use. You can learn a lot from experimenting with prettyprinting, but this is just the extreme tip of the iceberg and if we keep at it this answer will turn into a lengthy tutorial. I might answer further questions if you post them, but I'm not going to walk you through it. Again, sorry.